# Run delete PHP/SQL only when checkbox is ticked

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I have the following scenario:

User can see all their logged entries, but wants to delete a single one. I have the following php part, but this deletes everything from the table (which is fine), but disregards if the checkbox is ticked or not. It should only delete when the checkbox is ticked:

```
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $query = "DELETE FROM `trips` WHERE `id` > 1" ; 
    // this changes later to user specific instances - only example for now

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(isset($_POST['deletecheck']) && $_POST['deletecheck'] == 'Yes' )
    {
     $conn->query($query) == TRUE;
      echo "deleted";
    }
    else
         {
     echo "ERROR: tick the checkbox and press delete to delete the trip";
     }   

     ?>
```

Comment: You're querying twice here. And should get back a "1" as an error, but you didn't check for it using `mysqli_error($conn)`. Check if they're set, then query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute your query two times.

in `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);` (the one causing your unexpected behavior) and `$conn->query($query) == TRUE;`

Just delete `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);` and you should be fine with it.

For sure you should improve your code anyway, but this one line is causing your actual problem

Comment: thanks, this works. And I agree - my code should improve :)

Comment: No problem, mate. Just keep working on it and improve yourself by experience :)